# Magento 2.3.7 Problem Forgot Password letters and numbers don't displayed on the page

Tags: magento, forgot-password

When the client forgot your password the form is incorrect in the page the letters and numbers of recaptcha are not displayed in the page and the client don't get reset our password.How can I solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAda8.png)

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that reCaptcha is enabled and configured at store > configuration > security. If no, you won't see reCaptcha at frontend.

For customers not receiving transactional email when the password is forgotten, I would try:

1. check if there is any reindex required. If you haven't run upgrade and compile commands, it may be the issue as well.
2. Magento 2 requires to install SMTP module to send emails. If you bought a module, you may talk with the developers to check if it comes with SMTP or if any additional extension is required.